# Add the number of words starting with particular letters until they are >=100, then start again with the next letter

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sum

I have a list of addresses for which I have the number of addresses that start with each letter of the alphabet. I would like to add A + B and see if it is less than or equal to 100. I don't want much more than 100 addresses per chunk if that makes sense. If A + B is >= 100, I want to put that value in a cell and then see if there are more than 100 records for "C" addresses. If there aren't, I'd like to add C + D and see if the number is >= 100, and so on. If A + B is less than 100, I need to add A + B + C and see if that is >=100.

This is a picture of the data

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far, but I think rather than copying this multiple times, there should be an easier way to tell Excel to step through the letters until the sum is >=100. I'm just not sure how to do it.

```
Dim sumAB As Integer
    sumAB = Range("AF2").Value + Range("AF3").Value
    Range("AI2").Value = sumAB
    Range("AH2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "A-B"
        If sumAB >= 100 Then
            Range("AJ2").Value = sumAB
            Else  'do nothing
        End If
        
    Dim sumABC As Integer
    sumABC = Range("AF2").Value + Range("AF3").Value + Range("AF4").Value
    Range("AI3").Value = sumABC
    Range("AH3").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = " A-C"
        If sumABC >= 100 Then
            Range("AJ3").Value = sumABC
            Else
        End If
```

Comment: Which columns contain addresses for how many rows?

Comment: The columns that contain addresses are columns B through K. The number of rows is variable every day.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the following code:

```
For i = 2 To 27
        alphasum = alphasum + Application.Cells(i, 32).Value
            If alphasum >= 100 Then
                Application.Cells(i, 35).Value = alphasum
                alphasum = 0
                    Else 'do nothing
            End If
        Next i
```